# How to convert sql file to a specific formatted csv file?

Tags: sql, csv, url, export, push

Any ideas how I can extract data from a SQL database, put it into a CSV file in a specific format and push it to an external url?

Comment: This would depend on what database you are using, so you should tag your question with the relevant database.

Answer (score 0):

Most SQL databases have some sort of Export utility that can produce a CSV file. Google "Export " and you should find it. It is not a part of SQL standard, so every product does it differently.